# In which function of my uiviewcontroller should I set position and size of programmatically created uiviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller which I created with IB, It has a CollectionView that will load some data, during loading process I want to show an activity indicator. For that I set the center property on activityIndicator to be equal to the center property of collectionView.

the problem is that I don't know on which method of viewController should I do this. I tried it first inside viewDidLoad method but inside this method the frame of collectionView is equal to what it was inside IB and activityIndicator can't be set properly.

So my questions are :

1. I want to know where should I do this kind of positioning of UIView objects
2. When does ios sdk give the views the sizes they should have in respect of the device the app is running on not the IB.
3. What happens inside of viewController methods like viewDidLoad and viewWillLayoutSubviews when we call those methods on super object of viewController like `[super viewDidLoad]`

Comment: you should do this in viewDidAppear method... because views are in resizing process in viewDidLoad so it can happen that you don't get correct centre of view

Comment: I don't agree with the above, if you use autolayout or autoresize masks correctly it shouldn't matter. `viewDidAppear` the view is already on the screen. So if you layout your view in there everything will 'jump' into place

Answer (score 0):

All drawing-related operations should be performed on your `application’s main thread` then you could create it in the `viewDidLoad` or any other delegate function.

Threading Considerations

Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

// Call function here.

 })
```

For Reference [`UIView`] :
 (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

*1. I want to know where should I do this kind of positioning of UIView objects*

If you're using interface builder, you should be positioning them in interface builder using autolayout, otherwise pretty much anywhere on the main thread is fine. Sometimes you may need to call [self.view setNeedsLayout] / [self.view setNeedsDisplay] depending on what time of change you've made, but ultimately for normal `CGRectMake` calls you're fine.

*2. When does ios sdk give the views the sizes they should have in respect of the device the app is running on not the IB.*

UIView has a method called `layoutSubviews`
Otherwise for VC look at `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called either side of that

*3. What happens inside of viewController methods like viewDidLoad and viewWillLayoutSubviews when we call those methods on super object of viewController like [super viewDidLoad]*

In general for these methods you should call super at the top of the override to get whatever is happening underneath out of the way. Then proceed to work...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100.0f)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

The above will work completely fine. No need for `viewDidAppear`. Look into auto layout and auto resizing. Personally I think working in code and not interface builder is better... but that's a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) the great library to show activity indicator. Just downlod this from github. drag and drop `MBProgressHud.h` and `MBProgressHud.m` in your project. Import .h file in your class.

then call , `[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];`

and call when want to dissmiss or hide,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
// Do something...
//using main thread to hide immediately
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
});
});
```

It will automatically maintain center and other kind of stuff. That's it. Hope this will help. :)

Comment: I don't want to use libraries, I could if I would, I want to know what is the right way to do this kind of layout adjustments, and how view controller does the layouts.